# Java Hashmap - Iterate over a Hash and get all keys but the current one

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I´ve got a Problem more difficult: I would like to iterate over a Hashmap, but use EVERY OTHER Key but the current one.

Piece of Code:

```
for(String gkey: training_tables.keySet()){ 
        int i=0; 
        int notInConformation=0;
        int inConformation=0; 

        for(String akey: training_tables.get(gkey).keySet()){
            inConformation=inConformation+training_tables.get(gkey).get(akey)[i];
            for(String gxkey: training_tables.keySet()){
                if(!gxkey.equals(gkey)){
                    notInConformation+=training_tables.get(gxkey).get(akey)[i]; //OTHER keys; but not the current. 
                }
            }           
        }
        i++;
    }
```

It is a Hash containing a Hash containing an Integer Array;

```
//private final HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer[]>> training_tables;
```

I was looking for a Method to return everyother key; but the current one running in the outer for loop.

Annyways, after some thoughts, i solved the problem myself. I will still post this here as some people might want to know ;) 
The above code shows the solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Solution should be posted as an answer, not in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, can i change it still?

Comment: I think you can answer yourself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of java 8 using streams:

```
training_tables.keySet().stream().filter(e -> e != currentKey).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

returns all keys but the current one as a list

Comment: Thanks alot, id didnt thought of that one :)